# How do you know which variables gave a lift to my Y variable?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, multivariate-analysis, data-mining

Let's assume that I have Y (monthly sales data) and multiple variables (X1, X2, X3, X4, ....). Let's assume that I have fitted a regression model until the latest month and I got what features are contributing to my Y. Let's say (C1, C2, C3, C4, ...) are the contributions.

Once, I have next month data, if I fit another regression model and let's say (D1, D2, D3, D4, ...) are the new contributing factors, can I say that lift in contribution of X1 is (D1-C1)?

Can someone help me tell how can I explain this entire thing in a waterfall chart? (something like this - https://www.howtogeek.com/747405/how-to-create-and-customize-a-waterfall-chart-in-microsoft-excel/)